# How copy image to data directory in firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a html page which has input field(my panel html). I need get path to image(in my file system) from input and set it to `<img src = "path">`(in tab html). I know that browser don't allow to get absolute path to file.

Questions:

1) How can I copy image to my resource:data  directory to get images relative path and set it to my `<img src>`?

2) Are there another alternatives to set path in img src to any image in my file system?

Answer (score 2):

Please see Nandu's solution. You cannot set src of an image to a `file://` uri.

### Option 1

Make your panel.html a privileged page. Add a `chrome.manifest` file to your addon, and load the page into the panel with your `chrome://***/content/***` path and it can now load file uris.

OR register your resource page as an `about:` page with this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Custom_about:_URLs

### Option2

Create a `resource://` for it then set your src  to that.

You can create a resource like this:

let res = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
res.setSubstitution("myAddonId/myimg", Services.io.newURI('file://blah/blah/blah.png',null,null));

Then set src to `resource://myAddonId/myimg`

#### Option 3

XHR the image set the `responseType = 'blob'` and then on the resulting blob do `URL.createObjectURL` and then set the src of the img to that.

### To show a file dialog and get file path do this:

```
        var fp = Cc['@mozilla.org/filepicker;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIFilePicker);
        fp.init(Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'), 'Pick directory the icon container file should be saved in', Ci.nsIFilePicker.modeOpen);
        // fp.appendFilters(Ci.nsIFilePicker.filterAll);

        var rv = fp.show();
        if (rv == Ci.nsIFilePicker.returnOK || rv == Ci.nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {

            console.log('path to selected file:', fp.file.path);

        }// else { // cancelled }
```

Comment: Thanks my friend! You save me! I use second option and it works. I have one another question. Now user need to write absolute path of image in my input field in my tab page. When i try to use `<input type='file'>` as a value i get only image name. I read that browser don't allow to get absolute path to file. And my question is: Can i get files absolute path via <input type='file'> or somehow copy selected file in my `resource://Addon/data`?

Comment: @Sobir you are doing it from a privelaged scope so you can get the full file path, its mozilla specifc caled `mozFullPath` try that.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/mozFullPath

Comment: Sorry! I get problem. I used second option but it worked only once. After i start that code and it run but nothing happens.                                                            `var {Cc,Ci,Cu,Cr,Cm} = require("chrome");
var {Services} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");


let res = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
res.setSubstitution("test-addon/data", Services.io.newURI('file://C:/Averenges.jpg', null, null));`

Comment: I'm not sure @Sobir please make another topic so someone else can answer. I'm not sure.

Comment: Can I In option 3 copy the result blob file as image to my addon data directory? I try do that:                                                                            `var photo = window.URL.createObjectURL(game.photo);
        $('#image11').attr('src', photo);
        $("#image11").one("load", function() {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL($(this).attr('src'));
           //console.log($(this).attr('src'));
        }).each(function() {

            if(this.complete) {
                alert("Loaded");
                $(this).load();
            }
        });` But image isn't loading

Comment: @Sobir Your addon directory is a zipped file so no you cant put stuff into it. Well you can but you have to modify a locked file (its locked because its in use by the browser). you should do what jetpack does and store it in a folder in hte profile folder (`OS.Constants.Path.profileDir`) and then on uninstall of addon it should delete your files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:
1.) include image in the addon (under data folder) ex: data\image\panelimg.jpg
2.) in the panel.html file, you will reference img by it's relative path in reference to html file. ex:

You can only reference assets bundled with the add-on (and not any image in file system)

Comment: Great points. The only time you can set `src` of an image to a file uri (`file://`) is if the page is a privealged page such as a `chrome://` page or `about:` page.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer. How to do the html page privileged?

Comment: @Sobir Im not sure how to make it previelaged without making it a chrome or file path. Please post antoer stack question about that as Im eager to see how as well.